# how to access django admin site view model page when having change permission?

Tags: django, django-admin

When having change permission over a model we can only access editing mode when using django admin interface, How to access a record on view mode like users who have only view permissions ?

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you asking how to give view-only permissions to certain users (assuming you're using Django 2.1+)?

Comment: I want to make everybody to have access to edit mode + view mode. default django behaiviour is that only restricted users can access view mode

Comment: That's not really possible, since it's the same page (the change form), except that depending on permissions, some fields are displayed differently and the buttons are disabled. Also how would the user select which mode to use? You'd have to build this yourself, by creating your own views and tweaking with the templates. Best way is to look at the Django implementation for view-only users and reproduce that in your own views.

Comment: It seems strange to see /change in url while we are only on view mode, I think it deserve separate view and separate URL

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this is desired since permission is a good approach to control the accessibility, but if you do need a solution you may want to override the change_form.html template file as follows:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% endblock %}
{% block object-tools %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is desired because I have defined more visual field values in the view mode that I want all users to benifite from. however there is a unique link to access change and view model record, how to separate them ?